# EF Calling SaveChanges() Mutipletimes

Tags: entity-framework

We are building a Employee Time-Tracking program which has fields such as

```
------------------------
Employee Number: 2001
Time in: 9am
Time out: 5pm
Overtime: 0
------------------------
```

The client would like the option to ADD FOR ENTIRE WEEK CheckBox so they can enter data once and checkbox to all for entire week.

The business logic is crazy and I just need to call the SAVECHANGES() 5 times.

Question: How to I call the ctx.SAVECHANGES();  multiple times?
I have tried a ForEach and I have tried copy/paste ctx.SAVECHANGES(); several times without any luck.

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work. A second call to `SaveChanges()` would only have no effect if you did not make any changes to your entity set after the last `SaveChanges()`. But in general you will not have to call `SaveChanges()` more than once, because **a single call will commit all changes**.

Since you didn't specify your entities let's Imagine you have an `Employee` Entity and a `TimeSheet` Entity. The `TimeSheet` Entity has a foreign key relationship with the `Employee` Entity.

Then something like this should work:

```
using(var context = new TimeTrackingEntities())
{
  var emp = context.Employees.Where(x=>x.Id == 2001).Single();
  DateTime day = DateTime.Now.Date;

  for(int i=0;i<7; i++)
  { 
     TimeSheet t = new TimeSheet() {Employee = emp, Day = day, OtherProperties="here"};
     day = day.AddDays(1);
     context.TimeSheets.Add(t);
  }
  context.SaveChanges(); // save all timesheet additions
}
```

Comment: It worked great. I just kept the SaveChanges() outside of the FOR LOOP which contained the .ADD() method. -thank you!